# Jquery mobile select refresh, styles are comming out the wrong place

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Please take a look at this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GkfY7/

Can someone please explain to me, why the styling (and the text), not is being probably refreshed into the div?

I think the problem is in the refresh?

```
    $('#survey [data-role="fieldcontain"]').fieldcontain();
    $('#survey [data-role="fieldcontain"]').fieldcontain('refresh',true);
    $('#survey [data-role="controlgroup"]').controlgroup();
    $('#survey [data-role="controlgroup"]').controlgroup('refresh',true);
    $('#survey').selectmenu();
    $('#survey').selectmenu('refresh',true);
```

TIA,

Daniel

Comment: What's the styling you need?

Comment: The styling for jQuery Mobile... 
Right now there is one select - actually there should be two, they are in the DOM, but just not styled by jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Try Changing the last part of your code to:

        $('#survey').append(output.join(''));
        $('#survey [data-role="fieldcontain"]').fieldcontain();
        $('#survey [data-role="fieldcontain"]').fieldcontain('refresh',true);
        $('#survey [data-role="controlgroup"]').controlgroup();
        $('#survey [data-role="controlgroup"]').controlgroup('refresh',true);
        $('#sc1, #sc3').selectmenu();
        $('#sc1, #sc3').selectmenu('refresh',true);
```

Comment: Wauw! This worked...
Now I just need to "collect" all the #scX's into an array or string...

Comment: As a side note... My button doesn't catch the jQuery Mobile styling...? - Fixed

Comment: Try using (using the type=submit)                    $('[type="submit"]').button();
            $('[type="submit"]').button('refresh');